# Jest: Test recursive call inside Promise

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm having some problems testing the following class.

```
interface Connector {
   connect: () => Promise<void>;
}

class Unit {
   private connector: Connector;

   constructor(connector: Connector) {
      this.connector = connector;
   }

   public attemptConnect(iteration: number, max: number): void {
      console.log("attempt" + iteration);

      this.connector.connect()
         .then(() => {
            console.log("connected");
         })
         .catch((error) => {
            if (iteration < max) {
               this.attemptConnect(iteration + 1, max);
            }
         });
   }
}
```

I would like to test that the Connector.connect() function is called the right amount of times.
I'm trying to achieve that with jest as follows:

```
describe("Unit", () => {
   it("fails to record more than one recursion", async () => {
      const connector: Connector = {
         connect: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error("foo")),
      };
      const unit: Unit = new Unit(connector);

      await unit.attemptConnect(1, 4);

      expect((connector.connect as jest.Mock).mock.calls.length).toBe(4);
   });
});
```

Unfortunately the expect() call fails, saying

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 4
Received: 1
```

If I use a debugger and watch the value of

```
(connector.connect as jest.Mock).mock.calls.length
```

I can see the calls being correctly recorded. Only when the test finishes the number is wrong.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Return the promise in `attemptConnect()`:

```
public attemptConnect(iteration: number, max: number): Promise<void> {
  console.log("attempt" + iteration);

  return this.connector.connect()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("connected");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (iteration < max) {
        return this.attemptConnect(iteration + 1, max);
      }
    });
}
```

**Solution 2**

`await` for the required number of event loop cycles in the test:

```
describe("Unit", () => {
  it("fails to record more than one recursion", async () => {
    const connector: Connector = {
      connect: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error("foo")),
    };
    const unit: Unit = new Unit(connector);

    unit.attemptConnect(1, 4);

    // await enough event loop cycles for all the callbacks queued
    // by then() and catch() to run, in this case 5:
    await Promise.resolve().then().then().then().then();

    expect((connector.connect as jest.Mock).mock.calls.length).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

**Details**

The test awaits `attemptConnect()` but since it is not returning anything there is nothing to `await` and the synchronous test continues executing.  The `expect()` runs and fails before the callbacks queued by `then()` and `catch()` have a chance to run.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there also a solution that works if the promise is not returned?

Comment: @Treecj yes, I added it to my answer